# Concatenate multiple rows of HTML data

Tags: html, sql-server, concatenation

I have a database column called InfoBlob (nvarchar(MAX)).  I may have multiple rows in my table for the same email address.  So, I need to combine them for the one email address.

I have tried:

```
    select 
    STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT '|' + InfoBlob 
    FROM [dbo].[US_Quotes]
    WHERE [EmailAddress] = uq.[EmailAddress]
    FOR XML PATH (''))
    ,1,1,'')
from dbo.US_Quotes uq
```

However, this turns my `<p><b>Cruise Name:</b>&nbsp;BLAH</p>` 
into `&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Cruise Name:&lt;/b&gt;&amp;nbsp;BLAH&lt;/p&gt;`

Any ideas on how I can keep my HTML???  I am on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: well, for XML is always going to output certain characters like that, so your options are to either do a tedious set of replace statements, or use a different method for concatenation (e.g. a recursive cte)

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of a recursive CTE?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this: `declare @ table (i int, j nvarchar(max));
insert @ values (1, '<hi>'), (1, '<there>'), (1, '<buddy>'), (2, '<hello>'), (2, '<kitty>');
with t as (
 select i, j, row_number() over (partition by i order by (select null)) rn
 from @)
, recursiveCTE as (
 select i, j, rn
 from t
 where rn = 1
 union all
 select t.i, cast(recursiveCTE.j + '|' + t.j as nvarchar(max)), t.rn
 from t
 join recursiveCTE on recursiveCTE.rn = t.rn-1 and t.i = recursiveCTE.i)
select max(j)/*,i*/ concatstring from recursiveCTE group by i;`

Comment: Without sample data and a desired output, it's hard to really say what would work best for you, but there's a lot of examples of recursive CTEs on the internet. But really, it looks like you just need to concatenate a bunch of stuff, and you'd do that by just going over each email address and concatenating the infoblobs, I guess... How you do that depends on your desired result.

Comment: It sounds like your issue is actually the HTML encoding? Try searching for [SQL HTML encode](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+html+encode), there are some good explanations and solutions already.